# iPhone in app mail not returning to the application

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, sendmail

I am new to iOS development. I had created an iOS application. In my app, when an email is detected , I had written code to launch the default email application in iPhone.

And upto this, it was working fine. The default iPhone compose mail interface is launching and I can send the mail.

But the problem is after sending the mail,the control is not returning back to the app.
What can I do to return the control back to my app ?

Experts please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of launching the default email application in iPhone, use [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) interface to send email.

See [here](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-in-app-email/) for more refernce.

Answer (score 0):

Dismiss the mail view in  MFMailComposeViewController delegate method "didFinishWithResult"

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

All the best.